# c# Lambda with operation inside from string

Tags: c#, lambda

I try to convert a filed with lambda definition to function.

```
(sourceAggr) => {
                   var val1 = Convert.ToDecimal(sourceAggr[0].Value);
                   var val2 =Convert.ToDecimal(sourceAggr[1].Value);
                   return val1/val2;
                }, new object[2]{12,24}
```

I know the input (`object[]`) and the output and the idea is to write

```
fieldFromDb.convertToLambda(),new object[2]{12,24}
```

Comment: Lambda expression is a short hand replacement of delegates.. So what you need is to write a delegate

Comment: @RajshekarReddy ok but the idea is write a delegate compiled at run time not static

Comment: delegates can point to any method that compiles to its signature, So when you mean "write a delegate that is compiled at run time" Do you mean to say that you want to execute different methods depending on some logic of yours ?

Answer (score 0):

@RajshekarReddy the idea is write text string and convert it to function. I found a solution with Nreco module LambdaParser https://github.com/nreco/lambdaparser/